# Try to get the sum of even numbers in an array using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I want to get the sum of even numbers in an array:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[4];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 2;
    array[3] = 4;

    System.out.println("Count even: " + countE(array, 0));      
 }   

public static int countE(int[] arr, int head) {
        if (arr.length == head) {
        return -1;
        } else if (arr[head] % 2 == 0) {              

            return 1 + countE(arr, head + 1);
    } else {

        return 0 + countE(arr, head + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The output should give me the count of even numbers, in my main method I have an array of length 4 and there are 3 even number..it gives me the count as 2

Comment: Why are you using recursion for a linear problem? Recursion is the wrong approach here.

Comment: I'm supposed to use recursion here.( We're working on recursion )

Comment: paste your complete code including the array and calling code

Comment: @JimGarrison The beauty of recursion here is there are no mutations

Comment: What if the list contains 1 million items? Stackoverflow (literally). If you're going to teach recursion you should pick a recursive problem, not shoehorn it into a linear problem.  Choosing the correct algorithm is half the problem, and this approach teaches the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (arr.length == head) {
        return -1;
```

is giving you problem bro... You are subtracting 1 from the final count... try doing

```
if (arr.length == head) {
        return 0;
```

Comment: I found the problem it was in the last elose statment..basically I should  return " arr[0] +countE(arr, head+1)

Comment: @user2851858 Try again with a different input; something like a 2 as the first element and everything else be 1.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by recursion , you are adding the numbers wrong

```
        else if (arr[head]%2==0)
        {
            return arr[head] +  countHead(arr, head + 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives you 2 because in the last recursion, it deducts 1 -- your base case is wrong. Return 0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not revealing too much for you, it takes away the excitement of learning!

```
public static int countE(int[] array, int index) {
  int currentNumber = array[index];
  if(index == array.length) {
    // terminate it by returning a value that does not affect the sum (what integer is this?)
  } else {
    // check if even, if even, add the current number, else, add zero (both are recursive calls)
    if(isEven(currentNumber)) {
       return // your recursive call if even, currentNumber should be added
    } else {
       return // your recursive call if not, currentNumber should not be added
    }
  }
}

public static boolean isEven(int number) {
  return (number % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hlo. Buddy.. Try this

```
package com.smk.recursion;

public class SumOfEvenNoFromArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[5];
    a[0] = 2;
    a[1] = 5;
    a[2] = 4;
    a[3] = 4;
    a[4] = 4;

    System.out.println("Sum of Odd Numbers : "+sumEvenNoRecursion(a,(a.length-1)));

}

public static int sumEvenNoRecursion(int[] arr, int index){
    int sum;
    if(index == -1){
        return 0;
    }else if(arr[index]%2 == 0 ){           
        sum = arr[index] + sumEvenNoRecursion(arr, --index);            
    }else{
        sum =  sumEvenNoRecursion(arr, --index);            
    }
    return sum;


}
}
```

//OUtput

Sum of Odd Numbers : 14

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper function for the your recursion.

```
public static int sumofEvens(int[] list){
    int sum = sumHelper(list, 0, 0);
    return sum;
}
private static int sumHelper(int[] list, int i, int sum){
    if(i < list.length){
        if(list[i] % 2 == 0){
            sum += list[i];
        }
        sum = sumHelper(list, i+1, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```